# React - flicker / glitch unwanted effect on page reload. Conditional render

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a protected page (need to login to access) on a React web app.

App.js

```
<Route exact path="/restricted-zone" element={
  <ProtectedRoute>
    <RestrictedZone />
  </ProtectedRoute>
} />
```

ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { UserAuth } from "../context/AuthContext"

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const {auth} = UserAuth()

  if (! auth.currentUser) {
    return (
      <>
        <p>You need to sign in</p>
      </>
    )
  }
  return children
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

It works fine, but the page load has an unwanted weird, flicker, glitch

Attached a screen recording for better understanding of the problem.

[image: problem screen recording]

Edited according to @Jone's answer.

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged
} from "firebase/auth"
import { auth } from "../firebase"

const UserContext = createContext()

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children})  => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }

  const signIn = (email, password) => {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }

  const logout = () => {
    return signOut(auth)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser)
    })
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{createUser, user, auth, logout, signIn}}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The strange flickering is happening because React is rendering multiple times the same component according to state changes. Probably your custom Auth Hook is running async code, and when its execution is finished, the component updates.

In order to help you, please post the source code of your AuthContext, probably the issue is happening there

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question. Added AuthContext.js content.